# Cannot check if svn repository folders exists or not using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, svn

I am having some trouble with checking if a folder in the svn repository exists or not using a batch file.

Using a batch file, I see that in order to check if a folder exists I can do that using :

```
if exist c:/folder/ ( echo folder found )
if not exist c:/folder/ ( echo folder not found)
```

Using the same concept, but replacing the drive location to a svn repository location doesn't work.

```
if exist svn://repository_location ( echo folder found)
if not exist svn://repository_location ( echo folder not found )
```

Each time, I run the code, it gives back the error

> folder not found

Can anyone help me figure out some way to use the svn links to check for file locations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cmd.exe does not know anything about Subversion and the location svn://repository_location. Therefore, it will always output "folder not found" because there is no folder with name svn://repository_location on local filesystem.

You should use Subversion command-line tools (svn.exe, svnlook.exe) or use [its APIs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.developer.usingapi.html) to complete the task you have. There are also bindings for Python, C#, Perl which should help you.

Comment: I see. I will try integrating svn commands then. Thanks bahrep!